# Converting a Keras ConvLSTM2D output to input to a Conv2D

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a Model which I am using to feed in images and the aim of the model is to compare with a single image that is the output.

All/each image size = [96,96,3]

The Model takes in a folder where there are a total of 6 images, where 5 of them are kind of similar to the 6th image, and we have to use the 5 images (image Augmentation images) to predict the 6th image correctly.
The test-set and training-set has multiple of these folders

I decided to use CNN+LSTM to solve this problem, which I believe will do better than just using plain CNN to solve this problem, I already tried plain CNN and Image Augmentation which peaks in performance.

**Below is the model that I have currently, the part that is commented on is where I am having the issue.**

```
config.height = 96
config.width = 96
model = Sequential()
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', input_shape=(5, config.height, config.width, 3), return_sequences=True, stateful=False))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(ConvLSTM2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3,3), padding='same', return_sequences=True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
# LSTM_to_conv_dims = (-1, 96, 96, 3)
# model.add(Reshape(LSTM_to_conv_dims))
print(f'Shape of model {model.summary()}')
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
```

**To help the Output of this Model is for the model.summary() above**

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv_lst_m2d_1 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     40448     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_2 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     128       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_3 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     128       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_4 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     128       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 96, 96, 32)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_5 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 5, 96, 96, 3)      3792      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 5, 96, 96, 3)      12        
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 5, 96, 96, 3)      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 266,332
Trainable params: 266,070
Non-trainable params: 262
_________________________________________________________________
```

- The error I get is at the last Line of my Model when I am trying to
  reshape and put my BatchNorm_5 output to the Conv2D as the input.
- which I understand that needs to be changed to **[None, 96, 96, 3]**.
  Which is where I need the help of the community.
- Why I need this shape, is because my output image is of the same
  shape that needs to be compared to.
- I want to do this reshape with minimum loss of information.

**Error That I get, which is very correct, but I need ideas on how to correct this error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 154, in <module>
    model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  File "/home/sandeeppanku/anaconda3/envs/tensorflowpy1p11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 181, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/home/sandeeppanku/anaconda3/envs/tensorflowpy1p11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/home/sandeeppanku/anaconda3/envs/tensorflowpy1p11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 311, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `conv2d` in the last convlstm2d layer, you must change `return_sequences=True` to `return_sequences=False`. After you run the program, you can get `ndim=4`.